Error in coxme.fit(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights, : No starting estimate was successful : Cox regression models
I have the following dataset and I use R:
dummy_data <- data.frame(
  Area = c("VS", "VS", "VS", "VS", "VS", "VS", "VS"),
  Condition= c("T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T"),
  Date = as.Date(c("2012-12-01", "2012-12-01", "2012-12-01", "2012-12-01", "2012-12-01", "2012-      12-01", "2012-12-01")),
  Time = as.POSIXct(c("16:30:00", "16:30:00", "16:30:00", "16:30:00", "16:30:00", "16:30:00", "16:30:00"), format = "%H:%M:%S"),
  Replicate = c("T10", "T10", "T10", "T10", "T10", "T2", "T2"),
  ReplicateArea = c("T10VS", "T10VS", "T10VS", "T10VS", "T10VS", "T2VS", "T2VS"),
  CoVar = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  TimeInDays = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20),
  Death = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)

which represents the survival of organisms from different area, exposed to different conditions, along a time serie of date and time, summarized by the variable "timeindays", a covar noting the health disease state severity (continuous), and the death events (0 = alive, 1 = death)
I am building cox regression models with a nested random factor because the ReplicateArea is nested (representing which area is in which experiment) in Area because similar areas might react more similarly. My covar does not evolve with the time of the experience, hence the use of multivariate cox regressions.
Building the cox regression model with the random factor works:
cox_model <- coxme(Surv(TimeInDays, Death) ~ CoVar * Condition  + (1 | Area/ReplicateArea), data = dummy_data)

However, the model without the interaction between covar and conditions does not work:
cox_model_simple <- coxme(Surv(TimeInDays, Death) ~ CoVar + Condition  + (1 | Area/ReplicateArea), data = dummy_data)

and I get this error message :

"Error in coxme.fit(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
No starting estimate was successful"

If I try to build the model without the random factor:
cox_model_simple_Fixed <- coxph(Surv(TimeInDays, Death) ~ CoVar + Condition, data = dummy_data)

then I get "NAs" in the summary results for one of the Condition level. I tried to build coxph with conditions two by two to check where the issue is, and it seems to be only between two of those condition levels.
I checked my datasets and I have no NAs, or no strange symbols. Does anyone have any experience with this type of error?
I looked and many people have this kind of mistake when deleting levels of a factor, but that is not my case.

After looking more deeply into the error (and notably trying to build the models with datasets containing only three of the four conditions to filter where the error comes from), it appears that the ""Error in coxme.fit(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights, : No starting estimate was successful" appears for models that have the two conditions having the more constrasted survival (shortest being a few days, and the longest being more than a year). Would that mean that cox regressions don't work when the conditions have very different survival length?
